# Does NEST support updating index analysis?

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

As written in the elasticSearch documentation [here](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/admin-indices-update-settings/), it's possible to define a new analysis for an index (I tried and it worked fine).

I was wondering if it was possible to perform the same thing with NEST?

I tried this:

```
ElasticClient.CloseIndex("myindex");
IndexSettings ndxSettings = ElasticClient.GetIndexSettings("myindex").Settings; 
ndxSettings.Analysis.Analyzers.Add("snbowball", new SnowballAnalyzer());
var r = ElasticClient.UpdateSettings("myindex", ndxSettings);
ElasticClient.OpenIndex("myindex");
```

No error but nothing has changed.

When I try to see if the analyser has been added:

```
var getResponse = ElasticClient.GetIndexSettings("myindex");
```

`getResponse.Settings.Analysis.Analyzers` contains nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing the right thing, but analysis settings currently aren't on the UpdateWhiteList in NEST:

https://github.com/Mpdreamz/NEST/blob/master/src/Nest/Domain/Settings/IndexSettings.cs

Comment: Why did I not look at it earlier? Thanks! ;-)