# Nest and ElasticSearch - UpdateSettings

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

This may be already answered here: [Does NEST support updating index analysis?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18062308/does-nest-support-updating-index-analysis) but I am not sure I entirely understand the answer. I want to update an analysis. Specifically, I have created a CustomAnalyzer that is a fulltext search. I want to update this. It seems like I cannot. Do I have to remove it and recreate it?

Answer (score 1):

You can only update analysis settings (for new fields, new analysis components) by closing and reopening the index prior and after calling `.UpdateSettings()`.

In most cases its better to create a new index with the appropriate settings and reindex into that though.

http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-update-settings.html#update-settings-analysis